# error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1 on cent os

Tags: centos

I am newbie for Cent os. Installing phantomjs on Cent os. Followed below steps but still facing issue.

Steps :

1. curl -O https://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2.
2. tar xvf phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686.tar.bz2
3. cp phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin
4. sudo yum install freetype
5. sudo yum install fontconfig

Above all steps completed successfully but when I try to hit phantomjs, it shows error **"phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory."**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35):

Just make sure you successfully run

```
yum install fontconfig freetype freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libstdc++
```

and then try to install as usual.

Answer (score 7):

To remove this error.

```
# sudo yum install fontconfig
```

If you are still facing the error, Run

```
# sudo yum install fontconfig freetype libfreetype.so.6 libfontconfig.so.1 libstdc++.so.6
```

**Note :**
If you are using ubuntu or debian, use apt-get install to install this package.

Answer (score 1):

centos, NodeJS, html-pdf
`sudo yum install fontconfig` (worked for me)