# Phantom installation failed EACCES: permission denied - AWS - NodeJS - Can't deploy updated application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I've hosted a `NodeJS` backend on `Beanstalk` using an `EC2` instance. It was and is still working well with old code but now if I want to update the application by deploying new code, it gives me errors as:

```
> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
  > node install.js
  
  Considering PhantomJS found at /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
  Found PhantomJS at /usr/local/bin/phantomjs ...verifying
  Writing location.js file
  Error checking path, continuing Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/location.js'
      at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
      at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1362:35)
      at writeLocationFile (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/util.js:84:6)
      at Promise._successFn (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js:375:11)
      at nextTickCallback (/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/kew/kew.js:47:28)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
    errno: -13,
    syscall: 'open',
    code: 'EACCES',
    path: '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/location.js'
  }
  Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
  Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
  Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
  Removing /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
  Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1606204791845/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 -> /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
  Phantom installation failed [Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1606204791845/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom'] {
    errno: -13,
    code: 'EACCES',
    syscall: 'link',
    path: '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1606204791845/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64',
    dest: '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom'
  } Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1606204791845/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom'
```

I've been stuck with this situation for 20 days now, I've tried various solutions from the web but none has worked so far. I don't even know why there's `PhantomJS` in my code, maybe because of any 3rd party package I've added.

Solutions I've tried:

1. Tried installing/uninstalling `PhantomJS` from my project and then uploading it.
2. Tried installing it on the `EC2` Linux machine by taking access through `Putty` and using commands (support link used - [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)):

   ```
   sudo npm install phantomjs -g //Didn't work

   sudo npm install phantomjs@2.1.1 -g --unsafe-perm //Didn't work
   sudo npm install phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 -g --unsafe-perm

   //Installing globally using NPM support docs
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
   export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   source ~/.profile
   npm install -g phantomjs
   npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt
   NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global //also tried this
   ```
3. Tried this solution from official github repo issue [#722](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/722)

   ```
   cd /usr/local/share
   sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
   sudo tar xjf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
   ```

I've also tried many random solutions but so far nothing has worked. There was no `keypair` associated with my `EC2` instance, so accessing it was a separate mess. Also, Yes, I'm new to backend development.

**So,** my question is How to fix this `PhantomJS` issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old now, hope the OP managed to get it sorted!  Since I spent a couple of days trying to fix this myself, thought I'd drop some info in here of the things I did to solve this issue, taken from various sources, for anyone coming along later!

ssh to your eb environment using your AWS identity key (found in your home dir, ~/.ssh) and the dns of the application, the deployed name of the app assigned by AWS, e.g:

```
ssh -i <key>.pem <app name>-env.<chars>.<region>.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

Once you're in:

```
>cd /var/app/current directory.
```

create empty file

```
>touch .npmrc
>sudo vi .npmrc
```

place `unsafe-perm=true` into it and exit vi (press `<esc>` and type `:wq`).
This will allow the gyp process sparked up by npm to actually do something.

```
>sudo npm install phantomjs-prebuilt
...
>sudo yum install fontconfig
```

You'll need a way to have all this formalised and reproducible in a build process so you don't need to log in each time there's an update applied!!

Sources:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=290964

[error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1 on cent os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129742/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libfontconfig-so-1-on-cent-os/45129811)

Comment: Now, that I dont work on this, I can't try your solution but the only thing worked then was  I created a new server on EC2 and hosted the same app on that server's Beanstalk app. And, it worked on that without any such issues. But, yes, thank you for the answer, hope it helps someone.